# CALCUL WITH CONSTRUCTOR IN ENTITY SYMFONY

Tags: symfony, sonata

i need to do a **calcul** in an entity with symfony (sonata) like :
i have 3 labels in my entity with doctrine and i need to save in database a result of :
**$calcul = $ a + $b ;**

here is my entity

```
class National
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string(unique=true)
     */
    private $selection;
    
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $a;
    
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $b;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $total;
```

and this is my classic setter and getter

```
/**
     * Set a
     *
     * @param string $a
     *
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setA($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get a
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getA()
    {
        return $this->a;
    }
    
/**
     * Set b
     *
     * @param string $b
     * @return Events
     */
    public function setB($b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;

        return $this;
    }
```

so the question is **how to do the constructor** ???

to have the result in $calcul save in the database

*(ex: if i write 5 in label $a et 5 in label $b - i need to have 10 write directly in the label $calcul ....)*

Answer (score 0):

### Recommandation

I do not recommend to do such a thing as persisting calculated data to a database ([3FN Explanation](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2017/09/the-normal-forms-third-normal-form.html)).

In a general way you don't want to store a fields which is a result from two or more other fields, as if you need to update one of the original fields, this will also require you to re-calculated a re-store the result at each time, requiring a few more operations each time.

Also, if fore some reason the calcul must change, you'll have to update all of the data which was done with a former calcul. This will become very hard to manage.

If you need to retrieve the results of two or more fields, this should be perform by calling a function where you need it.

### Technicaly

Of course, if you still want to do that, or really need it, the way to do it would be :

```
class National {
   ... // Your fields, getters and setters
   public function calculTotal() {
      $this->total = $this->a + $this->b;
      return $this;
   }
}
```

In your controller or service

```
// Fetch you National entity from repository
// Perform the calcul
$national->calculTotal()
// Persist the national entity with the new 'total' fields added to it
$this->entityManager->perist($national);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Ok so the value exist and just when you construct the entity you want to calculate it ?
Then just call ``doCalcul()`` on the entity and your good ! You don't need to know $a and $b value.

Comment: admin.admin.national:
        class: AdminBundle\Admin\NationalAdmin
        arguments: [~, AdminBundle\Entity\National, AdminBundle\Controller\CalculController SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: VOTE, label: NATIONAL }

Comment: Please edit your question to provide new info

Comment: step 1 :         public function calculTotal() {
      $this->total = $this->a + $this->b;
      return $this;
   }

Comment: step 2 (the services) :  admin.admin.national:
        class: AdminBundle\Admin\NationalAdmin
        arguments: [~, AdminBundle\Entity\National, AdminBundle\Controller\CalculController, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: VOTE, label: NATIONAL }

Comment: step 3 (the controller) : <?php

// src/Tutorial/BlogBundle/Controller/CommentAdminController.php

namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController;

class CalculController extends CRUDController
{
 
 
// Fetch you National entity from repository   olivier toppin
// Perform the calcul
$national->calculTotal()
// Persist the national entity with the new 'total' fields added to it
$this->entityManager->perist($national2);
$this->entityManager->flush();


}